# How to use XML with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm very new To Android Studio, but I am pretty good with Java but have never really tried out XML. Whenever I search the web I can't really find any good tutorials on XML, and when I do they are irrelevant and the code is different then the one Android Studio uses. Do any of you know any good tutorials that teach you how to use XML in Android Studio? Thanks.

P.S This is the XML that I'm referring to: https://gyazo.com/9b86f01828dc130f964e126561049827

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered to be [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The XML you are referring to is a layout resource. It is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and pretty much any book or course on Android app development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android Studio 2.2

We got a new layout named as Constraint layout, which replaces xml,
If you learn how to use constraint layout, then there is no need open any xml file, except in some special cases.

Constraint layout is all about just drag and drop interface, where we can define our constraints too.

I found this udemy course to be useful,
https://www.udemy.com/master-android-7-nougat-java-app-development-step-by-step/